# How can i make an API wrapper for a HTTP service that uses json?

Tags: python

I want to make a HTTP wrapper for twitch.tv in python. How would I do this? I know how to use HTTP GET and that's about it. I would like it to work like this:

```
import twichtvwrapper
twich = twichtvwrapper(useragent, username, password).
channel = twich.channel(channelname)
```

then all the json properties would go in here like:

```
 print(channel.game) #this would say the last played game
 print(channel.displayname) #this would print the display name of the channel
 print(cahnnel.link.chat) #this will return the chat link
```

etc.

How would I go about making this wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert between Python dicts and JSON strings with the `json` module of the Standard Library.

```
import json

# package a python dict as json
dict0 = {'spam': 'data', 'eggs': 'more data'}
pack = json.dumps(dict0)

# turn it back to a dict
dict1 = json.loads(pack)

>>> print dict1['spam']
data
```

So, if your program gets a JSON response from a HTTP request, just convert it to a dict and use regular Python dict methods to do the rest.

Comment: When I try to run your code it doesn't work?!I'm using python 2.7.

Comment: It seemed strange that 'json.dump' would do both. Btw when is your android ide coming out? I want to run it on an eink display (NST), so can you make it compatible with android 2.1?

Comment: I'm just tidying up the stdout. I should have something pretty useful ready in a few weeks. I'll put iton GitHub about then, and just keep working on it. It should work with Android2.1, but I've not tested it.